# Take away number from mysql database using textbox mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a table with a a column called 'tickets' and it has a number in it.

I want the number in the mysql db to drop by what the user enters into a textbox.

So for example if the number in the db is 40 and the user enters 3, it will change to 37.

I have a feeling I would need to use an update query but I have no idea what it would be.

If anybody could provide a suggestion on how to do this it would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `SET column=column-3` or `SET column=column-$var` (`WHERE other_column='something'`) - *In a nutshell*

Comment: **subtract** instead of take away

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED** Based on your comments your query might look like this

```sql
UPDATE event
   SET tickets = tickets - $elliegoulding
 WHERE name = 'Ellie Goulding'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf6e1/2)** demo

Comment: I have taken this advice and tried to create a query which does not work, would you be able to take a look at it and see if you can spot an error? $sql = "UPDATE event SET tickets = 'tickets - $elliegoulding' WHERE name = 'Ellie Goulding";
$elliegoulding being the number the user entered in the box to subtract

Comment: @Andrew YOu are setting the value to the string `'tickets - $elliegoulding`. You should use "UPDATE event SET tickets = tickets - $elliegoulding WHERE name = 'Ellie Goulding", and of course, you should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

**Give this a go:**

Yours (old):
Remove the quotes in `'tickets - $elliegoulding'` and add one for `'Ellie Goulding`

```
$sql = "UPDATE event SET tickets = 'tickets - $elliegoulding' WHERE name = 'Ellie Goulding ";
                    remove quote --^         remove quote --^                 add quote --^
```

New:

```
$sql = "UPDATE event SET tickets = tickets - $elliegoulding WHERE name = 'Ellie Goulding'";
```